# clip-path polygon - cuts image but keeps original image size

Tags: html, css

the code snippet demonstrates the problem I face. When using clip-path: polygon, it cuts the image/div but keeps the original image size. This means space is being taken up redundantly, since the image has already been chopped. I'd like to have my div directly below .image-poly where the image that has been cut off still exists but isn't shown.

I hope this makes sense guys, this has had me stumped for around 30 minutes

```css
.image-poly{
clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 63%, 0 40%);}

.text{
background-color:black;
color:white;}
```

```html
<div class = "image-poly">
<img src = "http://www.qygjxz.com/data/out/193/3856596-random-image.png">
</div>

<div class = "text">
<p>ewfewfewfwefewfwefwef
ewfewfewfwefewfwefwef
ewfewfewfwefewfwefwef
ewfewfewfwefewfwefwef
ewfewfewfwefewfwefwef
</p>
</class>
```

Comment: Why dont you try postion :relative; for your text and align it wherever you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already said:

> When using clip-path: polygon, it cuts the image/div but keeps the
>   original image size

So sadly there is no way to make the div automatically flow into the "empty" space, because there is no empty space - the image is still just as big as before, it's just not displayed.

So if you really want to have your text directly underneath the image you will have to find another solution. You can for example overlap the text over the image, so that it looks like the text is directly beneath the remaining image part. However, keep in mind that that requires you to use `position: absolute`. Here is one example how you could do that:

```css
.image-poly{
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 63%, 0 40%);
}

.text{
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
    position: absolute;
    top: 190px;
    left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class = "image-poly">
    <img src = "http://www.qygjxz.com/data/out/193/3856596-random-image.png">
    </div>

    <div class = "text">
    <p>ewfewfewfwefewfwefwef
    ewfewfewfwefewfwefwef
    ewfewfewfwefewfwefwef
    ewfewfewfwefewfwefwef
    ewfewfewfwefewfwefwef
    </p>
```